rustfmt: disable formatting for comment
I have the following piece of code:
/*
long explanatory comment with some ascii art etc.
*/
#[test]
fn foo() {
    //...
}

I want to only disable rustfmt for my leading comment,
so I tried
#[rustfmt::skip]
/*
long explanatory comment with some ascii art etc.
*/
#[test]
fn foo() {
    // I want this to still be formatted.
}

but unfortunately that disabled formatting for the entire function.
Is there a feature to only disable formatting for the comment?
I'm thinking of something like the //clang-format: off comments.

I can't seem to get rustfmt to do anything to a block comment here on the playground (rustfmt is under Tools in the top right). Can you provide an example? Maybe I've just missed the case you're running into.

@kmdreko: Ah, this might not even by a problem by default, but I have the following in my rustfmt.toml:
max_width = 80 wrap_comments = true normalize_comments = true

Does this answer your question? How can I switch off rustfmt for a region of code instead of a single item? (unfortunately, there is no good answer, but that's the status of rustfmt, not Stack Overflow).

@ChayimFriedman: not really, as a comment is distinctly different from a "region of code". Following that answer and wrapping a comment with a module seems insane to me. I accepted the answer I got as that's probably as good as it's gonna get.

A comment is a region of code. Fundamentally, the answer is that there are no way to do that, but there might be workarounds.

@ChayimFriedman: I don't think there's any point in having a semantic nitpicking discussion here, so I won't. I think the fact that the answer that I got here would not be a solution for the other question should be sufficient proof for the differences between the two questions.

Okay, I agree. But this is problematic since the title is not correct then. So I changed it.

AFAIK, there is no such thing at the moment. But you can always workaround it in this way:
#[rustfmt::skip]
/*
long explanatory comment with some ascii art etc.
*/
#[test]
fn foo() {
    foo_impl();
}

#[cfg(test)]
fn foo_impl() {
    // I want this to still be formatted.
}

